# drawImage is slower in Internet Explorer when clipping is set

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, internet-explorer-11

My app draws same figure on the canvas multiple times. We figured out that we could draw it once on the hidden canvas and them just copy it to the target canvas.
We are using drawImage to copy image from offscreen canvas to main one. But drawImage is 72% slower when there is a clip region on the canvas, even when this region is same as size of the canvas (which essentially should be a no-op). 
Is there any way to overcome this perf issue? How do I do clipping on the canvas and drawImage (or any alternative) still performs well?

Demo test: http://jsperf.com/drawimage-with-clipping

(There is no perf difference in Chrome)

[image]

Comment: The thing is, I.E. has never been a browser, only a trojan horse or a virus, nothing more.

Comment: @GameAlchemist Sardonically off-topic! :-) To veer you towards relevance, do you think using compositing instead of clipping will help the questioner with their perf issue?

Comment: Yes, somehow off-topic. Sometimes i get tired reading, in the MDN doc,  that IE is only odd man out... Compositing can't make what clip does : after a few draws, it becomes impossible to predict the output... unless you use a temporary canvas, with a cost. If i where the O.P. i'd clip through an function that would do nothing if the clip area == the canvas area... No better solution i fear.